# Outlier Analysis on a 2D array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, outliers

I'm trying to do an outlier analysis on a 2D array values, my data looks like this:

```
10.836126    6.342457    6.359280    4.865735   11.332891
13.228078   17.779455   11.021488   10.057800   13.371285
11.350769   15.052270   10.556633    7.909101    7.627935
11.841888    4.655980    8.363947   10.808192   12.761605
2.534398    6.189042    6.987835    8.412396    8.166305
```

As per my assignments' requirement I need to eliminate all those values who are 1 standard deviation away from the mean, the point where I'm stuck is this:

mean of this set is =  9.9900   10.0057   10.0180   10.0051    9.9312  and

standard deviation is = 3.0257   3.0208   3.0119   2.9924   2.9868

I'm not able to figure how calculate the outliers based on this mean and standard deviation. Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

P.S : I'm completely new to both Matlab and data analysis. So, excuse me for any irrelevant information.

Comment: Add the s.d. to the mean and eliminate those values that are greater. Also, subtract the s.d. from the mean and eliminate those values that are less than.

Comment: Do you need to eliminate all those values which are 1 standard deviation away from the mean of each column or the whole data?

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar  Actually, I'm not clear on that but I believe I need to eliminated values from the whole data.

 Thank you so much for the help Anon. Could you please share some sample code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this operation on Matlab is performed using the [isoutlier function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isoutlier.html#inputarg_method). The mean-variance approach for detecting outliers (the one your are refering to in your question) is applied on the observations when the `method` parameter is passed as `mean` to the function call:

> *method — Method for determining outliers 'median' (default) | 'mean' |
>   'quartiles' | 'grubbs' | 'gesd'*
>
> **'mean'** Returns true for elements more than three standard deviations
>   from the mean. This method is faster but less robust than 'median'.

Unfortunately, it is based on `3` standard deviations away from the mean instead of only `1` standard deviation away from the mean. Hence, a custom code must be implemented. Given the matrix of observations `A`, this should work fine:

```
m = nanmean(A,1);
s = nanstd(A,1);    
lb = m - s;
ub = m + s;
is_outlier = ((A < lb) | (A > ub));
```

The `is_outlier` variable will be a matrix of logical values of the same size of `A`, in which `true` values indicate an outlier:

```
A = [
  10.836126  6.342457  6.359280  4.865735 11.332891;
  13.228078 17.779455 11.021488 10.057800 13.371285;
  11.350769 15.052270 10.556633  7.909101  7.627935;
  11.841888  4.655980  8.363947 10.808192 12.761605;
   2.534398  6.189042  6.987835  8.412396  8.166305
];

m = nanmean(A,1);
s = nanstd(A,1);    
lb = m - s;
ub = m + s;

is_outlier = ((A < lb) | (A > ub))

is_outlier =
   0   0   1   1   0
   0   1   1   0   1
   0   0   1   0   1
   0   1   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   1
```

The only doubt I have concerns the means and variances you provided. They differ from the ones you calculate on the given data:

```
A = [
  10.836126  6.342457  6.359280  4.865735 11.332891;
  13.228078 17.779455 11.021488 10.057800 13.371285;
  11.350769 15.052270 10.556633  7.909101  7.627935;
  11.841888  4.655980  8.363947 10.808192 12.761605;
   2.534398  6.189042  6.987835  8.412396  8.166305
];

m = nanmean(A,1)
s = nanstd(A,1)

m =
    9.9582518 10.0038408 8.6578366 8.4106448 10.6520042


s =
    3.79639885205053 5.33862997268428 1.86284269833871 2.062972979429 2.35083838144151
```

So if you have to use those instead, you can simply proceed as follows:

```
A = [
  10.836126  6.342457  6.359280  4.865735 11.332891;
  13.228078 17.779455 11.021488 10.057800 13.371285;
  11.350769 15.052270 10.556633  7.909101  7.627935;
  11.841888  4.655980  8.363947 10.808192 12.761605;
   2.534398  6.189042  6.987835  8.412396  8.166305
];

m = [9.9900 10.0057 10.0180 10.0051 9.9312];
s = [3.0257  3.0208  3.0119  2.9924 2.9868];

lb = m - s;
ub = m + s;

is_outlier = ((A < lb) | (A > ub))

is_outlier =
   0   1   1   1   0
   1   1   0   0   1
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   1   1   1   0   0
```

Once you know which elements of `A` must be considered as outliers, you can proceed treating them as you prefer. For example, you could set them to `NaN` as follows:

```
A(is_outlier) = NaN;
```

or you could remove all the columns containing one or more outlier as follows:

```
A(any(is_outlier),:) = [];
```

Consider that the more you increase the tolerance from the mean, the more the outliers become rare. Using the built-in [isoutlier function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isoutlier.html#inputarg_method), which is based on `3` standard deviations away from the mean, very few outliers are detected:

```
A = [
  10.836126  6.342457  6.359280  4.865735 11.332891;
  13.228078 17.779455 11.021488 10.057800 13.371285;
  11.350769 15.052270 10.556633  7.909101  7.627935;
  11.841888  4.655980  8.363947 10.808192 12.761605;
   2.534398  6.189042  6.987835  8.412396  8.166305
];

isoutlier(A) % lb = m - (3 * s) AND ub = m + (3 * s)

ans =
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! It really helps! Actually, my data was of size 10000 * 5, as I couldn't fit in all values in the questions I've only given a sample of the data. The mean and sigma were the values of original 10000 * 5 data, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Fine, then you can just use the first code snippet to get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of whole data is: `data_mu=mean(mean(data))` where data is a matrix of all your values.

And the standard deviation is: `data_std=std(std(data))`.

The only thing is that you should check the data is between lower and upper bond.

You should develop a code like below:

```
data_mu=mean(mean(data));
data_std=std(std(data));    
counter=0;
upper_bond=data_mu+data_std;
lower_bond=data_mu-data_std;
for i=1:size(data,1)
   for j=1:size(data,2)
      if data(i,j)>lower_bond && data(i,j)<upper_bond
         counter=counter+1;
         standard_data(counter)=data(i,j);
      end
   end
end
```